# Asp.Net MVC3, Bool Column null check

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public Nullable<bool> BROUGHT { get; set; } // EDMX generate this code, so I can not change this
```

I want to null check for the BROUHGT (DB) column.

so I write code like

```
if (table.BROUGHT != DBNull.Value && Convert.ToBoolean(table.BROUGHT)){..}
```

but the error message say,

```
Error   2   Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'System.DBNull' ...
```

How I null check for that column?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework is an ORM, and it's shiedling you from having to think about `DBNull.Value`.  So just check against `null` like you would in other C# code:

```
if (table.BROUGHT != null && table.BROUGHT.Value){..}
```

Not that since it's a nullable type, to get the actual `bool` value you have to either use the `.Value` property (as above) or cast it to a `bool`.

Comment: wow Thank you very much, does .Value works for nullable string too?

Comment: @Expertwannabe, strings are not (nullable) value types, so they are *either* `null` *or* a valid string.  No value property.

Comment: aha, I see. so for bool, int ,date and decimal types is ok with .Value. Thank you!

Comment: @Expertwannabe, yes, but *only* if they are *nullable* in the database too.  Otherwise they will just be ordinary `int`, `DateTime`, and `decimal` types that don't have (or require) a `.Value` property.  (and of course, it will be impossible for them to be null)